# Can't type in an edittext (android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText)

Tags: android, fonts, android-edittext, android-support-library

I can't figure out why I can't type in my EditText boxes!

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/hint_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text=""/>
```

It needs to be v7 because the fonts don't work otherwise... (If it is not v7 I can type in it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix, add lines:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```